# PostGIS - geocode and address standardization

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

Can you please help me ( I am not professional, If it is possible some easy explanation) how to proceed with address standardization and geocoding with Open Street Maps data (outside the US) in PostGIS?

I've add osm data into PostGIS over osm2pgsql, but I edit style file for columns like street, country code, city ... So I think I have all important informations about address. What should I do next? I need some steps how to proceed, and I next study required technologies.

I am working on Windows.

Comment: This site is for helping with specific issues you are having when implementing code, a program or process.  It's best if you Google (or something else) for the information you need and then post here if you have a problem implementing it.

Comment: sorry, but google was the first thing what I do, but informations which I found not help me

Comment: I googled "geocode osm2pgsql" and the first result looks promising: https://gist.github.com/jpetazzo/5177554 and should be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS TIGER Geocoder was built for the US but the functions could be altered by you to process other country data sets.  The TIGER data set contain roads (lines) with address information along with tables for city, county and state data which the functions of the Geocoder utilize.

Pleases see this link:  http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/Extras.html

If your road network already contains address information then you should be able to implement a geocoder.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've updated my question, can you check please?